# Is there a way to customize how a chatter post is laid out?

Tags: chatter, feeditem

I'm displaying a chatter feed on a visualforce page, and I can't find out if there is a way to remove or hide the profile picture and name of the user who posts, and to remove or hide the "Comment, Like, Share" links at the bottom of the post.

The code I'm using is really simple:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<h1>News Feed</h1>
  <chatter:feed entityId="0F9d0000000XbDZ" showPublisher="FALSE" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of hiding the links at the bottom of the post UNLESS you use a completely customized chatter page i.e., you have to build the whole chatter in visualforce.

This gives the feeds of a particular user.

```
feedItemPage = ChatterUtils.getNewsFeed(UserInfo.getUserId());
```

Use the above and put in a VF page repeat.  The comment/like/share buttons wont be visible by default.

The user/group is the subjectId. (This lets you post)

```
ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), subjectId, ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem, 'On vacation this week.');
```

The second parameter, subjectId is the ID of the parent this feed element is posted to. The value can be the ID of a user, group, or record, or the string me to indicate the context user.